# Irreducible variety over an algebraically closed field which admits only constant regular functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be an irreducible variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ such that $\mathcal O_X(X)\cong k$. Then is it true that $X$ is a complete variety ? If this is not true in general, what of we also assume $X$ is quasi-projective ?

Comment: If you remove a point from $\Bbb{C^2/(Z+iZ)^2}$ then the only holomorphic functions are constant but it is not complete ?

Comment: As @reuns pointed out, if $X$ is geometrically integral and projective and $\mathrm{Codim}(Z)\geqslant 2$ then $U=X-Z$ is certainly no longer projective (or even proper) but by Algebraic Hartog's Lemma we have that $\mathcal{O}(X)\to \mathcal{O}(U)$ is an isomorphism. But, geometrically integral and projective implies that $\mathcal{O}(X)=k$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: yes but projective varieties are complete ... sorry I didn't get your point ...

Comment: @user102248 He is saying that $X-Z$ (not $X$) also has only constant functions, but $X-Z$ is not complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to get this out of the unanswered queue.

We have the following nice proposition:

> **Theorem (Algebraic Hartog's Lemma):** Let $X$ be an integral normal (Noetherian so I don't scare myself) scheme and let $Z\subseteq X$ be a closed subscheme of dimension at least $2$. Let $U:=X-Z$. Then, the restriction map $\mathcal{O}(X)\to \mathcal{O}(U)$ is an isomorphism.

You can find a proof of this, for example, in Vakil's book. The point is that if $A$ is a normal integral domain then $A$ is actually equal to the intersection of all the $A_\mathfrak{p}$ as $\mathfrak{p}$ ranges over all height $1$ primes. In particular, since our $U$ contains all codimension $1$ subsets, we know that any function will be in ever $A_\mathfrak{p}$ and thus in $A$.

Anyways, assume now that $X$ is geometrically integral and projective. Then, $\mathcal{O}(X)=k$. Let $Z\subseteq X$ be codimension at least $2$ and set $U:=X-Z$. Note then that $U$ is not projective. In fact, it's not even proper else the map $U\to X$ would have closed image, which it doesn't. That said, by Algebraic Hartog's Lemma we have that $\mathcal{O}(U)=k$.

So, for example, if $n\geqslant 2$ then for any closed point $x\in\mathbb{P}^n_k$ we have that $\mathbb{P}^n_k-\{x\}$ is not projective but has global sections $k$.

Comment: thanks ... say what would happen if I also had assumed that every closed, irreducible sub-variety of $X$ also has only constant regular functions ?

Comment: @user102248 see here(https://lovelylittlelemmas.rjprojects.net/properness-and-completeness-of-curves/). I think it is true that a separated one-dimensional scheme of finite type over a field is proper iff its has a finite-dimensional space of global sections (basically because a non-proper scheme like this must be affine, and a finitely generated zero-dimensional algebra has discrete finite Spec). Then what you say would work (even if we restrict the assumption to one-dimensional subschemes). Alex probably knows more about this, so he might comment.

Comment: @user102248 I haven't actually checked, but it's conceivable that this implies proper. The point being that as Aknazar has pointed out for one-dimensional subs this implies proper. One might be able to bootstrap this to full properness using the fact that since your objects are Noetherian you can apply the valuative criterion for just DVRs which may, perhaps, allow you to just need to know that the curves are proper (e.g. see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0208). I'm not positive though--if you want to think through it and let me know if you have any questions that'd be best since I

Comment: probably won't have time to think about it in the next few days. @AknazarKazhymurat